# Ptracing syscalls

Tags: c, system-calls, ptrace

I've the following code:

```
void
attach_to_pid (int pid, char *username, int pts)
{
  int sys_call_nr = 0;
  struct user_regs_struct regs;
  ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
  waitpid (pid, 0, WCONTINUED);
  ptrace (PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0,
          PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD | PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT);
  while (true)
    {
      ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
      int status;
      waitpid (pid, &status, WCONTINUED);
      if (status == (SIGTRAP | PTRACE_EVENT_EXIT << 8))
        break;
      ptrace (PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);
#ifdef __i386__
      sys_call_nr = regs.eax;
#elif __x86_64__
      sys_call_nr = regs.rax;
#else
#error "Unsupported architecture."
#endif
      if (sys_call_nr == __NR_write)
        {
          printf ("read!");
        }
      ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
      waitpid (pid, &status, WCONTINUED);
ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS,pid,0,&regs);
printf("%d = %d\n",sys_call_nr,regs.eax);
//ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0 , 0);
    }
  ptrace (PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);
}
```

I'm obtaining strange results, as follows:

```
-514 = -38
-514 = -38
1 = -38
0 = -38
...
```

Normally, when stracing with `strace` an sshd session, I always obtain calls to the read and write syscalls when writing into the shell. But with that function, I am not obtaining that (fake I guess) syscalls, only (as you can see): 1, 0, and so on...

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: I guess, Linux Kernel is trapping sys calls on exit instead of on enter and on exit.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see in the eax/rax register? Are you looking for function names?

Answer (score 1):

Even I struggled on the same issue. And your question is an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503425/in-linux-on-entry-of-a-sys-call-what-is-the-value-in-eax-not-orig-eax)
The answer there is more beautifully explained. This  is my version:
 Your program needs to differentiate between a system call entry and system call exit. 
 Maintain a variable for that. Check out this [code](http://pastie.org/3627733). Here the variable `in_syscall` does the same. 
Hope this helps you.
Next time on-wards do a basic research (re-SEARCH) here before posting a question. SAVES A LOT OF YOUR TIME TOO ;) n ours too :D

Comment: @user1189104: Care to check for the answer for the Questions you posted ?? :P

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I solved my problem doing in different and similar way, I will post my solved code when finished another issue which is not working as I hope. Thanks a lot. P.D: I will do a search on that forum next time, don't worry. Thanks!

Comment: Look, it has passed long time ago since i asked this. Finally I could solve the problem, but doing some old tricks. As in the ptrace manual aren't supported all the options named, there wasn't an easy way of doing this. I don't remember exactly what I had to do, but for sure wasn't a normal -described-in-manual- programation. And there wasn't a way of knowing if catching an syscall_entry or an syscall_exit, so... but thanks wanyway. Ptrace nowadays continues being not very powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
  struct user_regs_struct regs /*_on_entry, regs_on_exit*/ ;
  ptrace (PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0);
  waitpid (pid, 0, WCONTINUED);
  while (true)
    {
      ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
      int status;
      wait (&status);
#ifdef __i386__
      int eax = ptrace (PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, ORIG_EAX * 4, 0);
      ptrace (PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);
      ptrace (PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
      waitpid (pid, &status, WCONTINUED);
      if (eax == __NR_read && regs.ebx == 10)
        {
          int *buffer = (int *) malloc (regs.eax + 3);
          int i = 0;
          for (int j = 0; i < regs.eax; i += 4, j++)
            {
              buffer[j] = ptrace (PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, regs.ecx + i, 0);
            }
          if (regs.edx % 4)     // rest of chunk.
            {
              buffer[i] =
                ptrace (PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, regs.ecx + 2 * i - regs.eax, 0);
            }
          write (1, buffer, regs.eax);
          free (buffer);
        }
#elif __x86_64__
#else
#error "Unsupported architecture."
#endif
    }
```

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: I am interested to see what your code does. And your work around for that problem is also different. If you don't mind can you share the code with us? You can paste your code [here](http://pastie.org/)

Comment: It's an sshd monitor. And it is not finished because I'm trying to patch openssh for that goal. Thanks for your interest. Hope this helps.

Comment: No comments? Allright, I think it passed long time ago, and had negative points here.. dont know why, really. GL

Comment: Sry bro.. stuck up with a Fk'd up job.. :( been long i opened a terminal :'( ill have a look .. thanks for coming bak ..